# Connect socket to sails from test

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to test sails socket connections from mocha.

```
    var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
    var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

    // Instantiate the socket client (`io`)
    // (for now, you must explicitly pass in the socket.io client when using this library from Node.js)
    var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

    // Set some options:
    // (you have to specify the host and port of the Sails backend when using this library from Node.js)
    io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
```

It gives an error

> Uncaught Error: The provided socket.io client (io) has already been
>   augmented into a Sails socket SDK instance (it has io.sails).

Am I doing something wrong? sails version 0.12.3, socket.io-client 1.4.6

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I also need to test my sockets in sails.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is posible because you have install multiples `sails.io.js`

You should view this line of code the [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/master/dist/sails.io.js#L393)

review your code

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow and thanks for helping. Please avoid linking externally wherever possible. If you refer to a single line then please quote it. If it is not a single line then edit your answer to give a summary of the relevant parts (and then additionally link to useful external additional information).

Comment: Do you have updated answer? I am also trying to test sockets from sails. I am using `Cloud` SDK and `sails.helpers.http.sendHttpRequest` to test HTTP endpoints per - https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/test/private/before.js#L56-L103 - any ideas for Sockets?

Answer (score 1):

I once ran into this problem wayback. It happened while I was using sockets to connect to  React.

A quick fix was to only call the io function just once i.e in React it worked by wrapping the sockets function in a componentDidMount function to ensure it only runs once even if refreshed.

Ensure this runs only once

```
 var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
 io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
```

by doing this

```
    let io;
if (socketIOClient.sails) {
  io = socketIOClient;
} else {
  io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
}
```

and you can say bye-bye to that nasty error

Comment: Could you please let me know this: how do you convert your suggested solution in Typescript? @Aqueous –